# Listings package handles keywords inconsistently

Tags: listings

I am using the `listings` package with pdfLaTeX and I notice that it handles keywords inconsistently. If I run the MWE at the bottom of my post,  I get this:

[image: Image of my output]

As you can see, "For" is handled differntly in lines 2 and 10. Also, "Dim" is treated as a keyword. But in `\lstset` I said `\deletekeyword{Dim}`.

But it doesn't stop there: If I completely remove line 12 I get the following output:[image: Image of my output 2]

Suddenly, "STR" is treated like a keyword (line 14); "Next" and "Do" aren't anymore (lines 15 and 19).

How can this be and how can I fix it?

```
%% MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\def\arr{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,x=1em,y=1em,baseline={(0,-0.35em)}]
        \draw [->](-0.4,0) -- (0.4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\def\arrend{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,x=1em,y=1em,baseline={(0,-0.3em)}]
        \draw[<-] (-0.25,0) -- (0.25,0) -- (0.25,0.3); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\def\sp{\bfseries\textvisiblespace}
\lstset{
    language=[Visual]Basic,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\underbar,
    keepspaces=true,
    frame=tBlR,
    rulesepcolor=\color[RGB]{204,0,0},
    numbers=left,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    morekeywords={To,LpWhile,IfEnd,Step},
    deletekeywords={Dim},
    literate={->}{\arr}1 {;}{\arrend}1{=/}{$\neq$}1
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstline=1,caption={\texttt{SCORE} (Set Parameters)\label{score}},escapechar=!]
{6,16} -> Dim Mat Z;
For 1 -> I To 6;
    -1!\textsc{e}!7 -> Mat Z[I,16];
Next;
ClrText;
"Boolean(show)"? -> D";
"Amount"? -> F;
4 -> X;
4 -> Y;
For 1 -> Mat Z[I,16];
    ClrText;
    Locate 1,2,"GIVE NAMES!\sp\sp!?:;
    Locate 13,2,S;
    Locate 3,4,"(!\sp\sp\sp\sp\sp\sp!)";
    Prog "STR IN";
Next;
0 -> H;
7 -> X;
3 -> Y;
Do;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quotation marks were unbalanced in the row #6 which upset the parser. I removed the extra `"` after the `D`. This was also true for `"GIVE NAMES"`

**EDIT** the `Dim` problem was instead that you had to delete the keyword from list 4 for Basic.

```
    %% MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\def\arr{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,x=1em,y=1em,baseline={(0,-0.35em)}]
        \draw [->](-0.4,0) -- (0.4,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\def\arrend{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,x=1em,y=1em,baseline={(0,-0.3em)}]
        \draw[<-] (-0.25,0) -- (0.25,0) -- (0.25,0.3); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\def\sp{\bfseries\textvisiblespace}
\lstset{
    language=[Visual]Basic,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\underbar,
    keepspaces=true,
    frame=tBlR,
    rulesepcolor=\color[RGB]{204,0,0},
    numbers=left,
    tabsize=2,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    morekeywords={To,LpWhile,IfEnd,Step},
    deletekeywords=[4]{Dim},
    literate={->}{\arr}1 {;}{\arrend}1{=/}{$\neq$}1
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[firstline=1,caption={\texttt{SCORE} (Set Parameters)\label{score}},escapechar=!]
{6,16} -> Dim Mat Z;
For 1 -> I To 6;
    -1!\textsc{e}!7 -> Mat Z[I,16];
Next;
ClrText;
"Boolean(show)"? -> D;
"Amount"? -> F;
4 -> X;
4 -> Y;
For 1 -> Mat Z[I,16];
    ClrText;
    Locate 1,2,"GIVE NAMES"!\sp\sp!?:;
    Locate 13,2,S;
    Locate 3,4,"(!\sp\sp\sp\sp\sp\sp!)";
    Prog "STR IN";
Next;
0 -> H;
7 -> X;
3 -> Y;
Do;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From a programming point of view I  also am unsure about line #10 since the for syntax is different from the first for (i.e. `for 1->I to 6` the first, but the `I to` is missing in the second)

**EDIT2**

Regarding the `list 4` here are some remarks:

1. the correct usage of `deletekeywords` is `deletekeywords=[number]{keywordlist}` where the number indicates in which one of the keyword set for the language definition the specific keywords are located. I think you'd better check out the `listings` package documentation for more insight about it
2. Ok but how do I find where the keyword is defined? Well there is this complementary file `lstdrvrs` which contains the language definitions included in `listings`. You can obtain its documentation from [ctan](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.pdf), or typing in your terminal `texdoc lstdrvrs`. Basic language should be around pages 12-15; at the bottom of page 14 you find `Dim` (suggestion: try for searching `Dim` and see whether it corresponds to Basic). You will promptly see that it is in `morekeywords=[4]`, ie list 4

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could miss that `" `100 times over.  I am curious to know more about the "list 4 stuff". What list is this, and how can I know when I need this option in future code blocks?

Comment: @gebruiker **believe me** the `"` stuff I missed for 10+ minutes. About the lists I'll make an add to the answer in a minute

Comment: P.S. Don't worry about the programming point of view. That's not the actual line I wrote. I just deleted some stuff to make the MWE as short as possible, whilst keeping the error. It accidentally stopped making sense. But you're kind to mention it.

Comment: @gebruiker I added an explanation of the list 4 and such